# Упругое нецентральное соударение шаров разной массы и размеров на JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, физика, моделирование

Пишу физику для 2d игры. И вот такая функция проверяет столкновения:

```
function distance(obj1, obj2){ //проверка на столкновение
let xDist=obj1.x-obj2.x;  //расстояние по x
let yDist=obj1.y-obj2.y;

if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDist,2)+Math.pow(yDist,2))<=(obj1.radius + obj2.radius)){

//пересчет скоростей при столкновении
//для первого объекта
obj1.speedX = -(2*obj2.massa*obj2.speedX+obj1.speedX*(obj1.massa- 
obj2.massa))/(obj1.massa+obj2.massa);
obj1.speedY = -(2*obj2.massa*obj2.speedY+obj1.speedY*(obj1.massa- 
obj2.massa))/(obj1.massa+obj2.massa);
//для второго
obj2.speedX = -(2*obj1.massa*obj1.speedX+obj2.speedX*(obj2.massa- 
obj1.massa))/(obj2.massa+obj1.massa);
obj2.speedY = -(2*obj1.massa*obj1.speedY+obj2.speedY*(obj2.massa- 
obj1.massa))/(obj2.massa+obj1.massa);

return 1;               //если расстояние меньше, то они столкнулись
}
}
```

obj1.x- координата по x-у.
obj1.speedX- скорость по x-у.
obj1.massa- масса.

При таком просчете любые столкновения выглядят как будто бы соударение было центральным- одна окружность задевает вторую лишь слегка, и вторая должна отскочить в сторону, а она движется как будто бы вектор удара пришелся на центр массы. Вот можно попробовать(движение стрелками): https://codepen.io/hertzHe/pen/YzGeNJq
Как изменить вычисление векторов чтобы шары отскакивали физически правильно- при нецентральном соударении шаров разной массы и радиуса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Физика удара

Рассмотрим момент когда два шара коснулись друг друга. Введём систему координат в которой ось `X` совпадает с прямой соединяющей центры шаров. Ось `Y` перпендикулярна.

В этой системе координат вертикальные скорости в момент удара не изменятся. Горизонтальные скорости поменяются в соответствии физикой центрального удара, как если бы вертикальных скоростей не было вовсе.

### Рассчёт

Проектировать скорости можно так. `(x, y)` - отрезок соединяющий центры шаров, причём нормированный. Тогда проекция скорости `v` на это отрезок - скалярное произведение `vx = dot(v, (x, y))`. Проекция скорости на перпендикуляр - `vy = dot(v, (-y, x))`.

После того как вы обработали удар, то есть пересчитали горизонтальные состовляющие скоростей (`vx -> vx'`), вам нужно собрать из проекций новый вектор скорости: `v' = vx' * (x, y) + vy * (-y, x)`.

### Ещё рассчёт

Небольшое дополнение: проектировать на перпендикулярную ось не обязательно. Эта математика хороша тем что работает и на плоскости и в пространстве (тогда вектор центров будет иметь вид `(x, y, z)`):

`vx = dot(v, (x, y))` - проектируем скорость на прямую между центрами

`vn = v - vx * (x, y)` - нормальная состовляющая скорости в виде вектора

`vx -> vx'` - центральный удар на оси `X` (одномерный)

`v' = vx' * (x, y) + vn` - восстанавливаем полную скорость.

### Одномерный центральный удар

Скорость центра масс системы до удара. По закону сохранения она сохранится и после удара:

```
vx = (obj1.massa * vx1 + obj2.massa * vx2) / (obj1.massa + obj2.massa)
```

Изменение скоростей первого и второго тел (штрихи - скорости после удара). Тут формулировка такая: если центр масс неподвижен до удара, то скорости должны измениться на противоположные:

```
vx1 - vx = -(vx1' - vx)
vx2 - vx = -(vx2' - vx)
```

Откуда получаем:

```
vx1' = 2 * vx - vx1
vx2' = 2 * vx - vx2
```